# Is it possible to concatenate this INSERT query in and out of a if statment?

Tags: php, sql, insert, concatenation

I'm having a few issues with this silly query, was wondering is it possible to concatenate the following INSERT query inside the IF statement and outside it as well to complete the rest of the query. So I want the $orderid to be insert within the if statement and the rest of the last 3 variables outside the IF

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){

    $orderid=mysql_insert_id();

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM course WHERE serial='$serial'") or die(mysql_error()); 
    $fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
    $serial = $fetch['serial'];
    $price = $fetch['price'];

    mysql_query("INSERT into course_order_detail values ('$orderid','$serial','1','$price')") or die(mysql_error()); 

}
```

Oh and $orderid is from the previous insert query written in my code.

Comment: General advice: you use the old, deprecated and insecure `mysql` extension. Start using `mysqli` or `PDO` instead and learn about prepared statements.

Comment: Ok will surely check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Like this

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){

    $orderid=mysql_insert_id();

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM course WHERE serial='$serial'") or die(mysql_error()); 
    $fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
    $serial = $fetch['serial'];
    $price = $fetch['price'];

    $in = mysql_query("INSERT into course_order_detail values ('$orderid')") or die(mysql_error()); 
    $new_id = mysql_insert_id();
}

$up = mysql_query("UPDATE course_order_detail SET serial='$serial',quantity='1',price='$price' WHERE orderid = ".$new_id);
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot and let you know but logically makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [nested insert with select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html)

```
INSERT `into course_order_detail` SELECT '$orderid', serial, '1', price FROM course WHERE serial='$serial'
```

BTW **sanitize** your queries